# In Android, given a PID, how to know its current running activity and services?

Tags: android, process

From `getRunningAppProcesses()` , One can get all the PIDs of current running processes.

But given a PID, its process may currently carry an activity (on the top of the task stack) or multiple services, how to know the names of these activity or service?

Comment: What's a "current" activity or service? Especially with services; multiple can be running at once. With activities at least you could say the one that's on top of the stack...

Comment: @kabuko Good comments, I will clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

For services, you can call [`getRunningServices`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningServices%28int%29) and filter by pid. For activities, you could use [`getRunningTasks`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29), then retrieve the [`topActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html#topActivity) for each. You'd have to do something like filtering by package which you could get fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Handler   handler = new Handler(); 

            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() { 
                    Log.e("start", "stsrt");


                    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

                    for (int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++) {
                        Log.e("Running task", "Running task: " + procInfos.get(i).processName);
                    } 
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                } 
            }; 

            handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Code-only answers don't help much. Mind to add some description?

Comment: Dude you can read about RunningTaskInfo and RunningAppProcessInfo.[link]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html[link]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html@DerGolem